# Webp images are not previewing with the link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload, webp

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project. As I worked on converting all images into Webp format, the images (with Webp) are not previewing/displaying the image part with the link like when we share with someone on skype or slack.

Even if we try:
https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg
[image]

and https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp
(Even StackOverflow is not displaying the image through webp link)

Please see this:
[image]

The first link didn't render/preview the image, but 2nd showed.

Can anyone please advise on how to render the preview of the image with a link?

Comment: Could you please update with some code, what you tried and didn't work OR how you want it to work?

Comment: I have converted all images to Webp format, and when I send the image URL to anyone, like VIA Skype, the image link doesn't preview the image section.

Comment: I have updated the post again with the image.

Comment: Isn't that a limitation of Skype itself, maybe it only shows png, jpg and so on. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/webp-file-format-support/32a524c3-20e0-459a-8bc6-0d18ca9f0840

Comment: @Eyeslandic not limited to Skype, even if we share Webp on Slack, social channels like Facebook, LinkedIn, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I mean, maybe these just don't support image preview of webp images, at least Skype doesn't seem to do so. In that case there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Is there way to get this done?

Comment: @Harshita did you find a solution?